# Проблема с ssl сертификатами

Tags: apache, https, apache2

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как решить проблемму. Заказывали ssl сертификат, по незнаю при генерации указали имя хоста с www. Нам выдали сертификат. Теперь соответственно при переходе на https://www.site.com соединение шифрованное, а при переходе на https://site.com пишет что сертификат не действительный. Как настроить редирект что бы при переходе на https://site.com перекидывало на https://www.site.com. Пробовал через htaccess, не получилось. Веб-сервер: apache.

Comment: Как пробовали, что именно не получилось?

Comment: pyatak - В htaccess пробовал добавить RewriteRule ^site\.com(.*)$ https://www.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]. Не работает переадресация на https://www.site.com

Comment: так снтаксис .htaccess же другой.. или мне кажется?    Redirect 301 / https://www.site.com/